# Database structure for multiple user types

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, architecture, user-defined-type

I am developing a database that will store users of different types. Currently, there are only two types of users, `clients` and `agents`. In the future, there may be a new type of user, "`organization`," which will create and manage agents. The system also includes administrators, implemented through roles.

The idea is to have a "users" table, which is mainly responsible for login functionality (email and password, token, and other technical fields), and additional tables for each of the corresponding user types, which have their own unique set of columns. For example, agents may have fields such as specialty, experience, diplomas, etc. Currently, clients do not have any unique fields, but this may change in the future.

However, as I have not managed a database of this complexity before, I am interested in how to organize a few aspects:

1. Firstly, users can be any of the aforementioned types. For example,
   if a user is logged in as an agent, they should still be able to
   place an order.
2. Secondly, it is necessary to provide the ability to create clients
   or agents without creating a user account. For example, if a client
   contacts the company by phone or email, without registering on the
   website. It is also possible to add the "organization" type, where
   the organization's administrator can create agents with or without
   login credentials (saving the record in the "agent" table, without
   recording in the "user" table).
3. Thirdly, I would like to draw attention to the "appointment" table.
   The table contains foreign keys for clients and agents, not users.

The main problems I am facing are:

1. Duplication of basic data (first_name, last_name) for clients and
   agents, as this data is stored in the "user" table, but I need to be
   able to create clients and agents without a user account.
2. Doubts about the need for the "client" table, as it currently has no
   additional fields and complicates the system.

**Here's what I've got so far**
[image]

Comment: Note how WhiteOwl avoided UUIDs, spelled out names (not necessary to normalize simple strings), used fewer tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy, one-table solution:

```
create table Person (
   id integer primary key,
   first_name varchar(30),
   last_name varchar(30),
   is_agent bool,
   is_client bool,
   is_organisation bool
)
```

Another, slightly more complicated solution would be to use a secondary table:

```
create table Person (
   id integer primary key,
   first_name varchar(30),
   last_name varchar(30),
)

create table Person_Role(
   person_id integer foreign key references Person(id),
   role char(1) check (role in ('A', 'C', 'O'),
   primary key (person_id, role)
)
```

Or you can go to a full scale EAV:

```
create table Person (
   id integer primary key,
   first_name varchar(30),
   last_name varchar(30),
)

create table Person_Attribute(
   person_id integer foreign key references Person(id),
   attr_name varchar(10),
   attr_value varchar(255)
   primary key (person_id, attr_name)
)

--- And have a user like:
insert into Person values(1, 'John', 'Doe')
insert into Person_Attribute values(1, 'role', 'agent')
insert into Person_Attribute values(1, 'role', 'client')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And where is the best place to store login information in this case? I just need the ability to create clients and agents without registering individual users.

And can you explain why you are using id instead of uuid

Comment: Login? If you want to keep it simple, the `Person` table can also have a `password` field. If a `password` is empty - that user cannot login, if has something - can. But this assuming that client application is connecting to DB with some "super-user" password and the authentication would be on the client. Normal for web, bad for standalone application.

Comment: `uuid` or `id` - does not really matter in the example. As long as you see the primary key.
But if start a discussion of `uuid` vs `id` - you would find almost equal amount of pros and cons for both, which eventually lead to a personal preferences. I gravitate toward `id integer` for this task, since in this case I doubt you would have more than 9223372036854775807 people to exhaust the int64 used by most all DBMS today.
And work with integer is faster than with uuid, by minuscule amount, but tiny bit faster.